# Sort Control by 'if Contains'

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a dashboard with responses from a Google Sheet (imported from a Google Form). The multiple choice questions are working fantastically, but I'm trying to filter it with a Control (the dropdown list) based on a "checkmark" question from the Google Form.

With a "checkmark" question in a Google Form asking people to select multiple of their favorite fruits (i.e. "Apples," "Grapes," "Oranges," and "Blueberries"), I'd like the viewer to be able to filter other graphs (say, age and gender) by one specific option (i.e. "Grapes"). However, right now, the user sees options like "Apples, Grapes, Blueberries," "Apples, Blueberries," "Grapes, Oranges, Blueberries," or "Apples," with one or two options for each.

To create the "favorite fruit" graph, I made different metrics for each option with `COUNT(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Apple.*") THEN 1 ELSE null END)`, which works well.

I tried making a dimension to filter it, but because it's not working:

```
CASE
    When REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Apples.*") THEN "Apples"
    When REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Grapes.*") THEN "Grapes"
    When REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Oranges.*") THEN "Oranges"
    When REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Blueberries.*") THEN "Blueberries"
END
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a field for each fruit, to count the number of people who likes it:

```
Likes_Apples ---> CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Apples.*") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Likes_Grapes ---> CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Fruit, ".*Grapes.*") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
...
```

This way you can use each field as a metric in charts, compare them, etc.

Sadly, I can't think in a way to allow your users to filter who likes "Apples" or "Grapes" using a single ComboBox.  You'll need to create multiple ComboBox, each one to filter for a specific fruit.